# GitLab Variables not working to fail a pipeline if certain string is found in the files committed

Tags: java, bash, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wrote a bash script which fails a pipeline in Gitlab if a certain string is found in the newly added java files that are committed to a feature branch. When the MR pipeline runs each time this script is being compared with the target branch and checking if there are new java files that are being added to it. I used the Gitlab variables for the target branch of the MR. The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Target Branch = ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}"

$(git fetch origin "${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}")
STAGED_JAVA_FILES=$((git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only origin/"${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}"..."${CI_COMMIT_SHA}") | grep "\.java")

function print_error_message_in_red() {
  echo -e "\033[31mERROR: $1\033[0m"
}

echo "$STAGED_JAVA_FILES" | xargs grep --with-filename -n "string1" && {
  print_error_message_in_red "Found string1 instances as part of your MR"
  exit 1
}

echo "$STAGED_JAVA_FILES" | xargs grep --with-filename -n "string2" && {
  print_error_message_in_red "Found string2 instances as part of your MR"
  exit 1
}

echo "No string1 or string2 instances found"
```

I can see the changes locally and if I run the git commands individually in my local, I can see the new added java files which have that particular string. But the MR pipeline is passing saying it didn't find any instances of either of the strings.

I believe I used the right command for `$STAGED_FILES`. But still I'm sure where exactly it is going wrong. Can somebody help me recognize the correct way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to run your bash script locally, for example by setting `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=master` at the beginning. You should see several issues with your bash script

Comment: Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net and fix any issues that are identified.